# How to create MongoDB Replica Sets with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Lets say I've used the MongoDB Java driver to create the following:

```
public class MongoDBTest {

    public static final String MY_MONGO = "MyMongo";
    public static final String ROOT = "Root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoDBTest test = new MongoDBTest();
        test.createDocument();
    }

    public void createDocument() {
        MongoClient client = null;
        DB db = null;
        try {
            client = new MongoClient( "localhost", 27017 );
            db = client.getDB( MY_MONGO );
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException ignored) {
        }

        System.out.println( "Connected to database." );


        assert db != null;
        DBObject document = new BasicDBObject( "name", "Me" ).append( "Place", "NYC" );
        System.out.println("Inserting document: "+document);
        DBCollection collection = db.collectionExists( ROOT ) ? db.getCollection( ROOT ) : db.createCollection(
                ROOT,
                document
        );
        collection.insert( document );
    }
}
```

How can I convert this DB to a replica set with DBs running of ports 27017,27018 and 27019? 
If I can't convert this to a replica set, how do I create a replica set in the beginning itself?

Comment: Are you asking how to code the creation of replica set instances? Or are you just asking how to change your code to connect to a replica set?

Comment: The replica set creation is something the server administrator does (in this case, you, but not from your Java code).

Comment: @Neil Lunn yes, I'm asking about how to create replica set instances using Java.

Comment: Okay then. Now we have a category. This is really far too broad due to the nature of what replica sets are. While we could give a scenario for running on `localhost` this does not really apply when communicating with remote hosts. Read the general documentation. There are really far better deployment and automation tools for this than writing Java code.

Comment: Why can't the Java driver be used for this purpose? The hostnames and port numbers are arbitrary really. I am using mongodb driver in my Java application for storing user data, which requires a replica set.

Comment: You can set up the replica set using Java code since the driver can send arbitrary commands to the server, but the Java driver was not designed to do this very well or very conveniently. Use the mongo shell and check out the [replica set deployment tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-set-deployment/).